# Specifying a default datatype for the columns of an empty data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the following empty `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dats = data.table(
    pr.full=numeric(), mse.full=numeric(), rt.full=numeric(),
    pr.aicf=numeric(), mse.aicf=numeric(), rt.aicf=numeric(),
    pr.aicb=numeric(), mse.aicb=numeric(), rt.aicb=numeric(),
    pr.bicf=numeric(), mse.bicf=numeric(), rt.bicf=numeric(),
    pr.bicb=numeric(), mse.bicb=numeric(), rt.bicb=numeric(),
    pr.r_min=numeric(), mse.r_min=numeric(), rt.r_min=numeric(),
    pr.r_1se=numeric(), mse.r_1se=numeric(), rt.r_1se=numeric(),
    pr.l_min=numeric(), mse.l_min=numeric(), rt.l_min=numeric(),
    pr.l_1se=numeric(), mse.l_1se=numeric(), rt.l_1se=numeric(),
    pr.l_refit=numeric(), mse.l_refit=numeric(), rt.l_refit=numeric() 
)
```

Clearly there is a lot of redundancy in this specification: is there a better way to approach this - e.g.

- a `data.table` with a single rows of 30 0's
- overwrite the column names
- delete the row of 0's

That is also not pretty .. but better than above. Other/better solution(s) would be appreciated.

Comment: Something like `as.data.table(matrix(numeric(0),nrow=0,ncol=length(cols),dimnames=list(NULL,cols)))` (assuming `cols` contains the column names).

Comment: @nicola  Feel free to add an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like (`cols` is a vector with column names):

```
as.data.table(matrix(numeric(0),nrow=0,ncol=length(cols),dimnames=list(NULL,cols)))
```

It should be stressed that possibly no solution will be very elegant and R-ish. Usually, you don't let your object grow inside a loop, since it's very inefficient. Rather, you should preallocate your object and then fill the values.

Comment: Looking at the benchmarks, your solution is 10 times faster. I would say that this solution is better!

Comment: Will using `rbindlist` still be v slow?   I come from `scala` and adding objects is not slow - and pre-allocating when we might have dynamic data is discouraged.

Comment: if you're very concerned about speed. Why would you choose R in the first place?

Comment: Have you tried to do statistical analysis in `scala`?  With *what* libraries ;)  `R` has its strong points - but why not try to get to some extent the best of both worlds

Comment: can you add code for how to add one row? I can't get anything to work.

Comment: @javadba That looks like another request. I suggest you to ask a new question, in such a way you can add relevant details to have a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
vars <- c(paste0("var",1:10))

dats = data.table()
dats = dats[,{ans<-lapply(vars,function(x)numeric());names(ans)<-vars;ans}]
```

---

You of course replace the dummy content of `vars` with your variable names.

Comment: nice - should I use `rbindlist` instead of the concatenated `data.frame` into itself? I mean just for "habit" to build a pattern of using higher performance way to do appends?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Maybe there is a better solution. That's just my way.

Comment: no worries - `rbind` / `rbindlist` are just another way to append to `data.frame` - yours is also ok but might be slower for large `data.frame`'s

Answer (score 1):

First of all: I recommend you start working with a `tibble`, from the homonymous package.
[Here you can see a few good reasons why.](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html)
That said, the answer below works with both of `as.tibble` and `as.data.frame`.

```
library(purrr)
cnames <- c("pr.full", "mse.full", "rt.full", "pr.aicf", "mse.aicf", "rt.aicf", 
            "pr.aicb", "mse.aicb", "rt.aicb", "pr.bicf", "mse.bicf", "rt.bicf", 
            "pr.bicb", "mse.bicb", "rt.bicb", "pr.r_min", "mse.r_min", "rt.r_min", 
            "pr.r_1se", "mse.r_1se", "rt.r_1se", "pr.l_min", "mse.l_min", 
            "rt.l_min", "pr.l_1se", "mse.l_1se", "rt.l_1se", "pr.l_refit", 
            "mse.l_refit", "rt.l_refit")
dats <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=0,ncol=length(cnames),))
colnames(dats) <- cnames
dats[, 1:30] <- map(dats[, 1:30], as.numeric)
```

PS: both `tibble` and `purrr` packages are available together in the `tidyverse` package.

Comment: There are great reasons to use `data.table` over `tibble` - performance, subsetting,  and the array slicing notation .  If you prefer `tibble` that's fine.

Comment: That's not a helpful answer.

Comment: @AndreElrico This answer provides input data -- makes it better than the OP where such a thing should have appeared. Also, it does result in a data.frame, not a tibble.. very simple to setDT on that and have the OP's desired result.

Comment: @Frank I cannot see why anyone would go `tidyverse` in order `setDT`. Esp. when OP is so concerned about every bit of speed.

Comment: @AndreElrico (Sorry for the comment spam, btw) I don't think purrr is a bad fit with data.table, though I do not use it. I agree that pushing tibble makes no sense here, but I don't think the substance of the answer (the code) is unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

Same as Andre Elrico's answer, but with `rep`:

```
vars <- c(paste0("var",1:10))
res = setnames(setDT(rep(list(numeric()), length(vars))), vars)
```

*Comment*: I agree with the other commenters that this is probably an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), that is, that there is a better way to do what the OP is after. I only use empty data.tables for format testing with the vetr package, anyway.

Comment: Are you referring to  "you should know how much data you will have in advance"  and thus to pre-allocate the entire `data.frame` (possibly with 0 values)? It is not always the case that the amount of data is known in advance.

Comment: @javadba I am saying that there is no use case for this that I know of. I don't know what your plan is, but I suspect it is not a good way to go, eg, `for (i in 1:n) DT <- rbind(DT, f(i))` where `f(i)` returns one row at a time.

Comment: Yes that's the intent - and a use case I encounter with some regularity. The data processing itself drives how many output rows will be generated and is not known up front.  I understand this is less common in use cases for which `R` is used.